# Use query syntax in GroupBy with complex range variable

Tags: vb.net, linq

I have a LINQ query, where I want to group elements from a collection. I'm trying to use query syntax to achieve my result, but I can't figure out how to describe a more complex range variable using query syntax.

Using method syntax, this works:

```
Dim R = someCollection.GroupBy(Function(x)
                                       For Each cItem In x.Attributes
                                           If cItem.Name = "N1" Then Return cItem.Value
                                       Next
                                   End Function)
```

I tried doing this in query syntax, but failed. So this doesn't work and gives an error: `Range variable name can be inferred only from a simple or qualified name with no arguments.`

```
Dim R = From q In someCollection
            Group q By Function(x)
                           For Each cItem In q.Attributes
                               If cItem .Name = "N1" Then Return cItem .Value
                           Next
                       End Function
                Into Group
```

I tried various other versions, but to no avail. How can I group by a complex parameter using a query syntax? Or should just stick to method syntax?

Comment: Maybe `Group q By q.Attributes.FirstOrDefault(Function(a) a.Name = "N1")?.Value`.

Comment: By the way, it is NEVER acceptable to say that something "gives an error" without describing that error.

Comment: Wow. It seems, that I did not know about `FirstorDefault`. Yes this works. If you could write it as an answer, I will accept this.
Thanks for noting my incomplete description. Edited the original.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `For Each` loop that exits the first time a condition is satisfied can generally be collapsed into a single call to `First`, `FirstOrDefault`, `Single` or `SingleOrDefault`.  In this case, the best option depends on whether there will always be one match or there can be none or more than one.

Always one: Single
Never more than one: SingleOrDefault
Never less than one: First
None, one or many: FirstOrDefault

In this case, assuming the last case:

```
Group q By q.Attributes.FirstOrDefault(Function(a) a.Name = "N1")?.Value
```

Null propagation is used because the "OrDefault" means that `Nothing` may be returned.

Comment: In my case there could either be no matches or exactly one match, so then, I suppose, `SingleOrDefault` would work equally well. But `FirstOrDefault` seems safer in case of corrupt input data. Thank you for the elaborate explanation. I learned quite a few things from this.

Comment: `SingleOrDefault` is the more correct option in that case.  The difference is that it will throw an exception if there are multiple matches.  That may sound undesirable but that's what should happen when your application is in an invalid state.  It's worth noting that some LINQ providers don't support both, e.g. LINQ to Entities only supports `First` and `FirstOrDefault`.  I suspect that is because the SQL generated from the query has no way to chance that there weren't multiple matches.